# Help needed using wp_trim_words

Tags: excerpt

I'm using a modified theme that came supplied with a 3rd party script which runs along side wordpress. The script files are unfortunately encrypted so I'm hoping to achieve what I want by editing the theme template. 
Currently the main wordpress index is displaying all content from each post, I would like to limit this to just a snippet to avoid any duplicate content problems.

I believe I can use wp_trim_words to do this but have been unable to get this working with the theme.

```
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                   <?php cb_build_single_blog_index_table(get_the_ID(), get_permalink(), get_the_tag_list('', __( ', ', 'twentyeleven' )), get_the_time(), get_the_date('c'), get_post_time('F d, Y'), $settings_detail['enable_tags']); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Is this even possible? Many thanks

Comment: yes possible, you can limit the post content in several way, but i am not really sure, if you are asking for limiting excerpt or post content, you can do this by [get_the_content()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147898/how-to-set-character-limit-on-the-content-and-the-excerpt-in-wordpress) have the at the answer here,  or [get_the_excerpt](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_excerpt), try doing this inside [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that a post excerpt is not always just the first X words of a post, so while `wp_trim_words()` could work under certain situations, it's a pretty rigid solution.

If you don't want to deal with reverse-engineering the encrypted/obfuscated source file (shame on whoever did that), you might be able to get clever using the `the_content` filter:

```
/**
 * Prevent the_content() from being used on the homepage 
 * or in post archives.
 *
 * @param string $content The post content.
 * @return The post excerpt.
 */
function wpse257975_swap_content_for_excerpt( $content ) {
  if ( is_archive() || is_home() ) {
    return get_the_excerpt( get_the_ID() );
  }

  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse257975_swap_content_for_excerpt', 1 );
```

It's definitely rather hacky, but this function (which will only work in the loop, BTW), will override the post content with the post excerpt on archive and the blog homepage.

I'd recommend adjusting the conditional to be *very* specific to the pages you need the excerpt on, and be sure to test this in a development environment before rolling it out to production. The *best* solution would still be to change the inner workings of `cb_build_single_blog_index_table()` to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I had previously attempted to decode the files and although they were for the most part readable, they were unusable. Sadly I am not proficient enough to fix the decoded files. I think you have pointed me in the right direction using the filter though. Thanks again.